# Why should I use $cacheFactory over manually getting/setting the data?

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference between manually maintaining an object variable as a cache, and following $cacheFactory way by Angular?

By 'manually' I mean something like this-

```
var cacheObj = {};

function setCache(data){
    cacheObj = data;
}

function getCache(){
    return cacheObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage would be that you're using something that is already available instead of reinventing the wheel. The $cacheFactory exists and already gets used by Angular anyways, for storing templates through the $templateFactory which is simply a 'templates' entry in the $cacheFactory. If you enable caching for $http without providing a cache, the $cacheFactory gets used by default.

So you have the choice to put your own time into creating something that already exists, this could be useful if the $cacheFactory doesn't do what you want it to, but in that case you could choose to extend the $cacheFactory instead of simply completely rewriting one yourself.

All in all, the $cacheFactory more than likely does everything you'd want from a caching service.

Comment: Thanks.. I think this sums up all